How to use Dockerfile ADD to add private repository using .ssh/config and/or debug said process
I would like to use the Dockerfile specifications ADD command to add a private repository to my image, as described in the documentation here:

Adding private Git repositories
To add a private repository via SSH, create a Dockerfile with the following form:
syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM alpine
ADD git@git.example.com:foo/bar.git /bar

This Dockerfile can be built with docker build --ssh or buildctl build --ssh, e.g.,
 docker build --ssh default


This uses the -ssh flag (or ssh option in the docker compose file build specification as described here).
However, I also need to be able to use ~/.ssh/config to get the right SSH-User-ID for ssh. My .ssh/config looks like:
Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com
  User <SSH-User-ID>
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/codecommit_rsa


When I use the following in my Dockerfile:
ADD --keep-git-dir=true ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/<repo-name>#master <repo-dir>

and the following in my compose.yml:
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: ./api
      ssh:
        - default=${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}
...

I get:
 > [api] git://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/<repo-name>#master:
0.799 root@git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
0.800 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
0.800 
0.800 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
0.800 and the repository exists.
------
failed to solve: failed to load cache key: failed to fetch remote ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/<repo-name>: git error: exit status 128
stderr:
root@git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Which seems to indicate it is not using the config to get the ID (i.e. root@git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com should be <SSH-User-ID>@git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com).
